# Symfony2 JsonResponse - ordering by value

Tags: json, symfony

I have 2 dropdowns were content of the second one depends on the first one. I produce it's content by generating an array and passing it to JsonResponse

```
 new JsonResponse($response_object);
```

My $response_object is created based on the list in the database where array keys match entity ID:

```
   6 => 'A Item',
   3 => 'B Item',
   1 => 'C Item',
   10 => 'D Item'
```

Problem is, that even tho I'm passing that list to JsonResponse as displayed (sorted by value), it displays it in the dropdown ordered by the key, not value.

This is how I build the response_object

```
  foreach ($entities as $entity) {
      $response_object->entities[$entity->getId()] = $entity->getName()
  }

  $response = new JsonResponse($response_object);
  return $response;
```

Twig is a simple for widget

```
  {{ form_widget(select_current_form.entity) }
```

Config in form builder for this particular field is

```
  ->add('entity', 'choice', array('required' => false, 'choices' => $entity_choices))
```

How to force it to display the list in order by value?

Comment: What happens if you `print_r($response_object->entities);`  Are you positive it is sorted by the entity's name and not value?  Where is the Twig code that produces the drop-down?

Comment: I edited my question. I'm positive that it's in a correct order just before creating JsonResponse object. When checking under Network in chrome inspector, response shows correct array sorted by value, however Preview displays same array sorted by key

Comment: Are you using form events as specified here?  http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#cookbook-form-events-submitted-data

Comment: Not aware of using events. Don't see them. I got someone else's code to debug so trying to figure out myself what's going on

Answer (score 0):

You can maybe try to use string as key in your array. Remember that you can use [natsort](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.natsort.php) to easily sort your array.

Comment: This would work but it breaks whole system... Form has to pass ID from the selection.

Also, natsort won't help because array comes out correctly from php. Seems it's at js level that it gets reordered

Comment: If you return a JSON, I suppose that you request an API in AJAX. Can you past this code?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing an array to the *JsonResponse*, if you pass an object you will be able to preserve its sorting.

Instead of this,

```
6 => 'A Item',
3 => 'B Item',
1 => 'C Item',
10 => 'D Item'
```

Arrange your function to bring an array of objects like this. (In PDO, you can use **\PDO::FETCH_OBJ** fetch mode)

```
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 6
        [value] => A Item
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 3
        [value] => B Item
    )

[2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 1
        [value] => C Item
    )
[3] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 10
        [value] => D Item
    )
```

I hope someone will find this helpful.